# How to implement multi select textbox in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

1. I want to implement multiselect textbox using only AngularJS. I am new in AngularJS, please help me.
2. I have implemented the same using jQuery now I would like to implement in angularJS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maku/TXPJZ/ Check out this jsfiddle if it helps you. Press and hold Ctrl button and then select options.

Comment: i need a multi selection in textbox

Comment: All I could think of a multi selection in textbox is concept of Tagging. Check out this Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3i6mrrwbAXrVAqW1ev8W?p=preview

Comment: Provide example with JQuery implementation, because right now it is hard to understand what are you trying to achieve here.